# MMC console stopped working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, mmc

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate.

I have recently started getting errors whenever I open anything that uses MMC - I get the standard error dialog saying that "The Management Console has stopped working". This also happens when I open the Event Viewer, so I can't get any info from that.

I can open MMC.exe, but when I load the Event Viewer (eventvwr.msc) from there, I get the same error.

Any input on how I can troubleshoot?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: first step run `sfc /scannow` additionally install any updates not already installed.

Comment: follow this and give me the dumps: http://pastebin.com/YTaQwd8p

Comment: @magicandre1981 - thanks a lot. I ran the .reg file, but it did not produce any dump files in the file system. I have saved it through Visual Studio instead: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3197547/mmc.zip

Comment: you get an internal .Net error: "Fatal Execution Engine Error (000007FEDC1CAF0E) (80131506)" See here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b89ca3a-6a93-4d21-a5eb-d5b5d44c6dce/clr-4030319239-internal-error-80131506?forum=clr